# Tkinter, widget inside widget inside a frame

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-layout

Ok, so game developing isn't knew for me, well not entirely.

So, I've been getting a window open(which I already did) and this window was going to display different frames when I need it to.

The code below opens the window and opens the frame:

```
from StartGame import Start_gameFrameTest
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image
def Game_window():
  window=Tk()
  window.title("C&D:FourSwords")
  window_width=window.winfo_screenwidth()
  window_height=window.winfo_screenheight()
  print(window_height,window_width)
  window.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d"%(window_width,window_height,0,0)) 
  window.resizable(width=True, height=True) 
  Menu=Start_gameFrameTest.Start_game(window_width,window_height)  
Game_window()
```

Then what it opens is this frame right here that is to display a button inside a label:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image
class Start_game(Frame):
    def __init__(game,window_width,window_height):
        game.window=super().__init__()
        game.background(window_width,window_height)
        game.Buttons(window_width,window_height)
        game.window.mainloop()
def background(game,window_width,window_height):
    game.window_width=window_width
    game.window_height=window_width
    game.file=open("directory.txt")
    game.name=game.file.read()
    game.photobg=Image.open(game.name)
    game.photobg=game.photobg.resize((window_width,window_height))
    game.imbg=ImageTk.PhotoImage(game.photobg)
    game.label=Label(game.window,image=game.imbg)
    game.label.image=game.imbg
    game.label.pack()
def Buttons(game,window_width,window_height):
    game.button_start=Button(game)
    game.photoB=Image.open(game.name)
    game.photoB=game.photoB.resize((100,200))
    game.imgb=ImageTk.PhotoImage(game.photoB)
    game.button_start.config(image=game.imgb)
    game.button_start.image=game.imgb
    game.button_start.place(game.window,in_=game.label, x=((window_width)/2),y=((window_height)/2))
```

This of course is really just a test sample but with the same problem, also here is the error code:

> Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64
>   bit  (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or
>   "license()" for more information.
>
> RESTART: D:\Create and
>   Destroy\FourSwords\Create_And_Destroy_Four_Swords.py  Traceback (most
>   recent call last): File "D:\Create and
>   Destroy\FourSwords\Create_And_Destroy_Four_Swords.py",  line 14, in
>       Game_window() File "D:\Create and
>   Destroy\FourSwords\Create_And_Destroy_Four_Swords.py",  line 13, in
>   Game_window
>   Menu=Start_gameFrameTest.Start_game(window_width,window_height) File
>   "D:\Create and Destroy\FourSwords\StartGame\Start_gameFrameTest.py",
>   line 8, in **init**    game.Buttons(window_width,window_height) File
>   "D:\Create and Destroy\FourSwords\StartGame\Start_gameFrameTest.py",
>   line 34, in Buttons
>   game.button_start.place(game.window,in_=game.label,
>   x=`((window_width)/2),y=((window_height)/2))File"C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",
>   line 2188, in place_configure
>   + self._options(cnf, kw))`_tkinter.TclError: can't place .!start_game.!button relative to .!label

And please don't do that thing this site does and just give oh you should use this and then walk away, please explain how and why I should use it.

it gets annoying for me who doesn't have time to trial and error your vague answer. Cause if I could do that then I wouldn't be here.

Comment: The last couple of sentences of your question are a bit insulting to people who might be willing to answer your question.

Comment: The code you present does not provide the error message stated in the post. Instead, I get: `ImportError: cannot import name 'Start_gameFrameTest'`. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).